# pdf link does not work with latex/dvips/pstopdf execution

Tags: hyperref, pdf, dvips

I have this simple LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
linkcolor=blue,
colorlinks=true,%         hyperlinks will be black
pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}% border style with underline of width 1pt
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Hello}
Hello.
\section{World}
World.
\end{document}
```

When I'm trying to get a pdf linked document with:

```
latex hello.tex
latex hello.tex
dvips hello.dvi
pstopdf hello.ps
```

I have a pdf file with blue links, but the link does not work. I had to use `pstopdf` instead of `ps2pdf` because the command is not available in my system (TeXLive 2014).

[image]

What might be wrong?

I need to use the `latex/dvips/pstopdf` command path, as I need to compile a TeX code from https://github.com/daly/literateclojure ; otherwise I get compilation errors.

Comment: Just a thought: have you tried `ps2pdf` instead of `pstopdf`?

Comment: @tohecz: I couldn't find ps2pdf which I was supposed to use from the original make file, I revised my question.

Comment: At which system you are? How did you install TL2014? Because `ps2pdf` should be installed by TL.

Comment: @tohecz: I use TL2014 on Mac OS X, but I can't find `ps2pdf`, I have `pstopdf` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I used `pstopdf`, not `ps2pdf`. It seems like that TL2014 distribution does not have `ps2pdf`, so I had to install `ps2pdf` with ghostscript from brew for Mac OS X.

```
brew install ghostscript
```